# laravel 5.3 Auth::user() not found

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am struggeling to get user authentication correct in a laravel 5.3 project.
To be sure of the configuration, I just started from a brand new project, but still no progress.

So these are my actions so far using https://laravel.com/docs/5.3

first downloading the latest laravel project

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

then installed using

```
laravel new website
```

opening this, shows me the laravel standard template, so I consider this as a successfull installation

[image]

now, I try to use the Auth module as described in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

showing:

[image]

I updated this in Controller.app, but "**Auth::user()**" is not possible as seen in this screenshot

[image]

This raises questions for me:

- what do I do wrong to get **Auth::user()** working as described in the manual?
- in laravel 5.2 I could write "**use Auth;**" in the controller using the alias as described in app.php, now the alias is found while tiping "use Auth", but still the "use ...." is written full after I type the alias and press enter. If I type "**use Auth;**" without pressing enter, the **Auth** throws an "undefined class" error. Is this an optional setting to use the alias names? or error in laravel?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Authentication Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#introduction).

You probably forgot to run `php artisan make:auth`.